# filter birthcountry in Sparql

Tags: filter, sparql

I'm getting into SPARQL and i would like to set an easy request, but it seems it's not that easy...

I would like to get all football players from a club that are born in a special country.

I have the request to get all players from a club. e.g.:

```
SELECT ?player WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hertha_BSC> dbpedia2:name ?player
}
```

How do I get all Players born in, e.g. Germany with the Filter option?

I already tried it this way, but it seems I'm not getting something...

```
prefix dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?player WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hertha_BSC> dbpedia2:name ?player .
?birth dbo:birthPlace ?player.
filter (regex(?birth, "Germany")).
}
```

I would appreciate if you could help me.

EDIT:
After Median Hilal help I am trying to get it done with "filter", but it ain't work.

```
SELECT distinct ?player WHERE {
?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer>. 
?player <http://dbpedia.org/property/currentclub> 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hertha_BSC>. 
optional {?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany>. }
filter (!bound(?subject)).
} 
ORDER BY ASC(?player)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your both queries make no sense. I think the following is useful

```
SELECT distinct * WHERE {
    ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer>. 
    #get all soccer players
    ?player <http://dbpedia.org/property/currentclub> ?club. 
    #get the clubs, you can use <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hertha_BSC> instead of ?club for Hertha Berlin
    ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country>? <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany>. 
    # get birth places which are either Germany or places located in Germany
}
```

Comment: Your solution makes more sense then the strange usage of `dbp:name` in the question. One minor comment: It doesn't really matter regarding the result, but I'd use `?` to cover the case *zero or one* instead using the asterisk `*` which covers *zero or more*.

Comment: Right! Modified!

Comment: I think @DaPole was wholeheartedly confused by these strange triples: `dbr:Hertha_BSC  dbp:name  dbr:Valentin_Stocker` etc. — see http://dbpedia.org/page/Hertha_BSC

Comment: Stanislav is right, I am confused by some things and this was one of them.
@MedianHilal thanks a lot, that really seems a lot more logic and get's the job done, but is there a posibility to get the country part with the option FILTER?